# C++ ostream operator << overloading

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a Card with parameters (Color, Value) and method to output Card's parameters.

Error binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'CardColor' and 'CardValue'(or there is no acceptable conversion)

**Card.h**

```
struct Card{
    Color CardColor;
    Value CardValue;

    Card(Color color, Value cardValue) {
        this->CardColor = color;
        this->CardValue = cardValue;
    }
    public:
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, const Card c);
};
```

**Value.h**

```
#ifndef VALUE_H
#define VALUE_H
enum class Value{ SEDMA, OSMA, DEVITKA, DESITKA, SPODEK, KRAL, ESO, SVRSEK };
#endif
```

**Color.h**

```
#ifndef COLOR_H
#define COLOR_H
enum class Color { ZALUD, LISTY, SRDCE, KULE };
#endif
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <Card.h>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, const Card c)
{
    output << c.CardColor << c.CardValue << std::endl;
    return output;
}

void outputCard(Card c)
{
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you copy+paste the complete error message here? Especially which operands the error message is talking about and possibly which line it is complaining about.

Comment: Do  `Color` and `Value` support `operator<<` too?

Comment: @Ultraviolet What? No!

Comment: While it should not matter, the second argument should really *also* be a reference.

Comment: What *we* really need to be able to help you is a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Is the `Card` structure nested inside another structure or class?

Comment: @nwp binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'CardColor' and 'CardValue' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Why do you copy the Card parameter in operator<<? Use a reference.

Comment: What that error means (you should really copy it, as text and in full and complete, and paste it into the *question body*, [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) is that you haven't overloaded `operator<<` for `Color` and `Value`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, card structure isnt inside another structure or class. I put the whole code

Comment: @M.Naro So, why not to post both `Color` and `Value` structs too?

Comment: The error message mentions a type `CardColor`, but there is no such type shown in your code.

Comment: @interjay:  `CardColor` and `CardValue` are data members and not types.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I know, but the error message says they are types, which means we aren't seeing the real code. I don't think this is the real error message either, because it doesn't make sense that it mentions two different types as being on the right hand side.

Comment: The root cause is that the OP is using `enum` **class**.  The compiler doesn't have default overloaded `operator<<` for `enum class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From you comment:

> binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'CardColor' and 'CardValue' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

You also need to provide `operator<<` for the Color and Value class.

example of this for the Color class:

```
#ifndef COLOR_H
#define COLOR_H

#include <iostream>

enum class Color { ZALUD, LISTY, SRDCE, KULE };

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Color& col)
{
    switch (col) {
      case ZALUD :
        os << "ZALUD";
        break;

      // ...
    }

    return os;
}

#endif
```